# xpath for href element inside a attribute

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I am dealing with pagination here. How can I get the href value from the below HTML selector? I can't use **//a[@data-page-number ='2']/@href** because the 2 changes to 3 when after every page.

```html
<a data-page-number="2" data-offset="30" href="/Restaurants-g297633-oa30-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS" class="nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk" onclick="      require('common/Radio')('restaurant-filters').emit('paginate', this.getAttribute('data-offset'));; ta.trackEventOnPage('STANDARD_PAGINATION', 'next', '2', 0); return false;
  ">
Next
</a>
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the site you working so I will be able to validate correctness of my answer?

Comment: @Prophet https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS

Comment: OK, it works for all the presented on the page pagination buttons. from 1 to 6 on the first page. When you will go to further pages it will present more pages but this should still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the `href` attribute of `next` button.

[image: devTools next button]

As you can see it has `next` value inside `onclick` attribute so we can use this to filter all the other `a` tags.

Example with [Scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```py
In [1]: url='https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html#EATERY_LIST_CON
   ...: TENTS'

In [2]: req = scrapy.Request(url=url)

In [3]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS> (referer: None)

In [4]: response.xpath('//a[contains(@onclick, "next")]/@href').get()
Out[4]: '/Restaurants-g297633-oa30-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//*[@class="unified pagination js_pageLinks"]/a[2]/@href
```

The above xpath expression for the next  pages meaning for pagination is working. `//*[@class="unified pagination js_pageLinks"]/a` selects both the previous and the next page url.So by slicing, you have to take the next page url.

Of course, when you will select element, turn of JavaScript, otherwise it will mix and match static element with dynamic.

**Full working code for the purpose of pagination:**

```
import scrapy
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tes'
    start_urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa60-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS']

    def parse(self, response):
        
        for card in response.xpath('//*[@class="zdCeB Vt o"]'):
            yield {'Title':card.xpath('.//a[@class="Lwqic Cj b"][1]//text()').getall()[-1]}

        next_page = response.xpath('//*[@class="unified pagination js_pageLinks"]/a[2]/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url,callback=self.parse)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Title': 'Vanitha Hotel'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1080-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html)
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'The Muyal RESTAURANT'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'K K R Food Products'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'Akathalam Homely Food'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'Thanneer Mathan Restaurant'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'Holly Hock'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'Cochin Halwa Centre'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'Canvas Restaurant Pizzeria'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'Canvas Restaurant & Pizzeria'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'Cafe Delaviz'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'Cafe Sora'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'Honey Dew Bakery'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g297633-oa1110-Kochi_Cochin_Ernakulam_District_Kerala.html>
{'Title': 'Food Barrel Restaurant'}
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-09-25 22:39:07 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 152484,
 'downloader/request_count': 36,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 36,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 4029630,
 'downloader/response_count': 36,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 36,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 62.328141,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 25, 16, 39, 7, 777225),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 22935503,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 36,
 'item_scraped_count': 1062,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
"//a[@data-page-number]/@href"
```

This will locate `a` tag element with `data-page-number` attribute. I guess this should be unique locator.
**UPD**
You are using a wrong tool for verifications.
[xpather.com](http://xpather.com/) is the better XPath expressions verification tool.
[image]

Comment: But still, I am not able to Isolate the @href from the a tag. The XPath mentioned above selects all the elements in the a tag.

Comment: What do you mean by `all the elements in the a tag`? What tools / technology do you use to extract the `href` value?

Comment: I use chrome tools for verifying the XPath. See the link. I have attached a screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/5QtvTRb

Comment: see my updated answer. The XPath I provided is correct.